# How to remove duplicate rows based on one column, retaining the first row for each

Tags: google-sheets

I want remove all row with equal date

```
02/03/2016  1   11  24  7   8   3   22
02/03/2016  1   11  23  7   8   3   22
03/03/2016  1   11  25  7   8   3   22
03/03/2016  1   11  25  8   7   3   22
04/03/2016  1   11  25  8   7   3   22
04/03/2016  1   11  25  7   8   3   22
04/03/2016  1   11  25  9   7   3   22
04/03/2016  1   11  25  9   8   3   22
```

After removal I want only

```
02/03/2016  1   11  24  7   8   3   22
03/03/2016  1   11  25  7   8   3   22
04/03/2016  1   11  25  8   7   3   22
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to retain only the **first** entry for each date. One way to do it is to filter by "column A entry not equal to the one above":

```
=filter(A2:H100, A2:A100 <> A1:A99)
```

The need to shift the indices in the comparison range may be a nuisance. Here's a version that does the shift itself:

```
=filter(A2:H100, A2:A100 <> offset(A2:A100, -1, 0))
```

However, neither of these two versions works with open-ended range like A2:H because offsetting it by -1 results in one more row. Here is a version that handles either kind of range:

```
=filter(A2:H, A2:H <> array_constrain(offset(A2:A, -1, 0), rows(A2:A), 1e7))
```

#### Apps Script function

This function deletes duplicate rows from the current sheet, following the same logic: delete a row if its A entry is equal to the one above it.

```
function removeDuplicateRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var firstColumn = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, 1).getValues();
  for (var i = rows; i >= 2; i--) {
    if (firstColumn[i-1][0] == firstColumn[i-2][0]) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks this works = filter (A2: H98; A2: A 98 <> A1: A97)
but I want a function like: removeDuplicateRows function () {.........

Comment: Okay, added it.

Comment: no work .... 
I also want it to be valid only for the range from A15 -> H100

Comment: Works in my spreadsheet. Have a good day.

Comment: . I want it to be valid only for the range from A15 -> H100  is possible?

Comment: Thanks this works!!! But only if value is text and not if value is date.
Can I with a function to format the column A as a text? Why automatically insert the dates and does not work

Comment: Are those really just dates, or do they also have a time part like 03:23:33? Because that would explain why they don't match.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

An alternative that works with open ended references.

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(UNIQUE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(A:A,COUNT(A:A),1)),A:H,column(A:H),1))
```

The above formula assumes that the data range doesn't have headers, but it could be easily adapted.

## Explanation

VLOOKUP is able to return an array that will be automatically expanded if it is inside an ARRAYFORMULA and it use ranges / arrays for some of its parameters.
Below are it the functions to get the three parameters of VLOOKUP.

### Parameter 1: Type of value -> Array

UNIQUE(range|array) is used to return an array of unique dates.
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(range|array,row_limit, column_limit) is used to left out the empty rows. This use COUNT(range|array) that works only for numbers/dates. It could be replaced by COUNTIF(range|array,"<>") in order to make it work both with text and numbers/dates

### Parameter 2: Type of value -> Range

The data range to be filtered.

### Parameter 3: Type of value -> Array

COLUMN(range) returns a an array of the indexes of each column.

### Parameter 4: Type of value -> Omitted

It's not included so the default value, TRUE, is applied.